# Vba - returning Shell explorer current path and then close it

Tags: shell, vba, path, directory, explorer

First of all, I must say that I'm running a code in a machine that has very few references installed and no Office at all.

I need to open an "explorer.exe" instance with the `Shell` command, browse through folders, enter in a selected (or newly created) one and finally click on "Ok" on a `MsgBox` (which pops up simultaneously) to close the `Shell` and return the selected folder path to a variable.

I have no idea how to achieve that. When I use `CurDir`, I end up getting a folder which is not the selected one.

Code used (which didn't work):

```
Sub BrowseForFolder()

ActualDir = "D:\"
Call Shell("C:\Windows\explorer", ActualDir, 1)

If Msgbox("Browse into folder or create a new one and then browse into it, then click ok", vbOkOnly, "Browse") = vbOk Then
    ' here should be the command to return the path. The following doesn't work since it returns always "D:\"
    ActualDir = CurDir
End If

' Here I have to close the Shell - I have no idea what to write to do it

End Sub
```

Comment: That's the wrong way: check [Shell.BrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. Are you using [tag:VBA] or [tag:VBScript]?

Comment: I'm using vba. I'll give it a shot right now and let you know if it works

Comment: No Office, so VBA in which environment? You may have better facilities from `Application`.

Comment: I'm working on an Agilent device which has its own built-in VBA. `Application` doesn't work. Anyway what you suggested was really helpful. Please have a look below for the final code that I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the code suggested by LS_dev which worked totally:

```
Private Sub SelectFolder_Click()

Dim objShell As Shell
```

Had to add the shell references

```
Dim ssfWINDOWS As Long
Dim objFolder As Folder2
```

for some reason "Folder" doesn't work

```
ssfWINDOWS = 36
Set objShell = New Shell
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, "D:\")

If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    FolderName = objFolder.Self.path
End If

Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```